# Why was my flag about profanity in a question denied?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

I flagged [a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76885314/discardvirtualmemory-could-not-be-located), because the user cursed. That is against the Code of Conduct, [as confirmed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22233) by a cofounder of SO. As a result, I thought my flag was pretty clear cut. However, I found that my flag was *"Declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention"*. I assumed this was an issue that "required intervention".

Comment: Did you perhaps flag because you thought it might lead to some form of punishment? Honest question, not trying to put you on the spot. You can probably already guess where this will be going if you answer "yes", so I will not in fact tag a lecture onto this :) Just food for thought.

Answer (score 28):

Just edit it out.  This isn't something that you *need* a mod to handle for you.

I mean, the post could also use a lot of other editing anyway, so diving in would be a useful exercise.

Comment: For context, we decline these types of flags for salvageable stuff. If it can be fixed with trivial editing (which anyone can do), it should be edited and not flagged. If the entire thing is an abusive rant (or crosses certain lines, particularly attacking people or groups of people), that's when mods get involved. A single expletive (that isn't a slur) used for emphasis doesn't qualify

Comment: @Zoe I just wanna add that if a user insists on using vulgar language (on multiple occasions), even if it is not a slur and the posts are salvageable, mods can/should be notified.

Comment: @M-- That is true - and if such is done through rollbacks, the system will automatically notify mods of rollback wars. In that case, if a user wants to flag, though, it's far preferable to use a mod attention flag and explain that the user is re-editing the post to contain profane content rather than just using a rude/abusive flag. Mods may overlook the edit history without being pointed in that direction.

Comment: @Catija great point. Honestly I wasn't thinking about rollback wars on the same post, but rather a user using inappropriate language on different posts. But for both of these cases, a custom mod flag is more suitable.

Comment: @Zoe - "which anyone can do" - the OP has < 2K rep, so the best they can do is suggest an edit, assuming the queue isn't full.

Comment: @snakecharmerb yes, and that still counts as something anyone can do. The edit queue being full is not a flag reason